# multiple conditions in while/if statement that runs if ANY of the conditions are true?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

From what I know, when you have multiple conditions in while or if-statements, all of them have to be true in order for the codeblock underneath to run.

My question is; Is it possible to have multiple conditions, but the codeblock underneath runs if any of those stated conditions are true? Meaning that one, two or all of them could be true and the while/if statement will be true?

Specifically in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the OR logic operator.

Example:

```
if(x==1 || x==2 || z==4)
{
    //code
}
```

the code will be executed when atleast one of the conditions in the if statement is true

Answer (score 1):

The thing You say happens when You use the "and" (&&) operator to connect conditions.Whith this operator all the conditions that you connect with && have to be all true to the total condition to be true.Instead,you can use the "or" (||) logic operator to evaluate the conditions and with only one true condition , the total condition will be true.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about is the difference between a logical AND and a logical OR.

The logical AND operator `&&` evaluates to true if both its operands evaluate to true.  In contrast, the logical OR operator `||` evaluates to true if either of its operands evaluate to true.

For example:

```
int a=3, b=4;

a>4 && b>5 // false
a>1 && b>5 // false
a>4 && b>3 // false
a>1 && b>3 // true
a>1 || b>3 // true
a>1 || b>5 // true
a>4 || b>3 // true
a>4 || b>5 // false
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is; Is it possible to have multiple conditions, but the
>   codeblock underneath runs if any of those stated conditions are true?
>   Meaning that one, two or all of them could be true and the while/if
>   statement will be true?

Yes, you can change this:

```
if (x) {code1}
if (y) {code2}
```

to this:

```
if (x || y) {code3}
```